# How to add many UIImageViews inside ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I will have about 12+ (any multiple of 4 per row) images that I want to have inside a ScrollView. See example below, the 12 circles (with the last row cut off a bit) are the UIImageViews.

I am not able to add the UIImageViews inside the ScrollView. The width,height of the scrollView is 250,250

This is what I have tried:

```
func setScrollView() {
    scrollView_avatars.contentSize = CGSizeMake(250,300);

    let imgView1: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "img1.jpg"))

    let imgView2: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "img2.jpg"))



    let imgView3: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "img3.jpg"))

    scrollView_avatars.addSubview(imgView1)

    scrollView_avatars.addSubview(imgView2)

    scrollView_avatars.addSubview(imgView3)

}
```

*iOS noob here*

[image]

My code above gives me very bizarre output, i think the sizes of the UIImageViews are not set correctly.

I dont also know how to position the UIImageViews within the ScrollView like only part of a image is visible.

Comment: You need to set the `frame` of each image view.

Comment: You could possibly do this more simply with a UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

As @rmaddy says, you need to set the frame properties on your views. You will need to do math to calculate their positions based on row/column position in your grid of views.

If you're using AutoLayout you may need to generate constraints to set the view's sizes and positions. (I haven't tried to add views to a scroll view in code with AutoLayout before, so I'm not totally positive what happens if you just set their frames without defining constraints.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your image views like this:

```
    if let image = UIImage(named: "myImage"){
      let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(yourXpoint, yourYpoint, image.size.width, image.size.height))
      imageView.image = image
    }
```

where yourXpoint and yourYpoint is where you want the image origin to be set, this way you are saying to swift where do you want the images to be place and what is its size.
The if let is just to be safe in case the image does not exist.
Another good option is to set constrains as it will make your app have a nice layout in al different screen sizes and orientation

Comment: You still need to give each image view a different origin.

Comment: Good point @rmaddy I edit the post to explicitly say that the origin should be set to the desired position not to 0, 0 always. Thanks